# Олимпиадная задача на нахождение площади

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, олимпиада

## Задача

Даны координаты вершин прямоугольника `x1, y1` и `x2, y2`. Точки, лежащие в этом прямоугольнике назовем *обработанными*. Точки, расстояние от которых до точки с координатами `x3, y3` не превышает `r`, назовем *облученными*. Требуется найти количество *обработанных и облученных* точек.

Иллюстрация для данных `x1=y1=0, x2=5, y2=4, x3=4, y3=0, r=3`:[image: пример]

Искомое количество точек в данном примере 14.

## Проблема

Вот мое решение:

```py
x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(int, input().split())
x3, y3, r = map(int, input().split())

if not (x3 in range(min(x1, x2), max(x1, x2) + 1) and y3 in range(min(y1, y2), max(y1, y2) + 1)):
    print('')
    exit()

w = min(abs(y2 - y3), r - 1) + min(abs(y1 - y3), r - 1) + 1
h = min(abs(x2 - x3), r - 1) + min(abs(x1 - x3), r - 1) + 1

corr = sum((abs(y2 - y3) >= r, abs(x3 - x1) >= r, abs(y1 - y3) >= r, abs(x2 - x3) >= r))

print((w * h) + corr)
```

На примере оно отрабатывает правильно, но дальше сыпется. Из моих ручных тестов следует, что оно выдает правильный ответ кроме тех случаев, когда точка `x3, y3` не лежит в прямоугольнике `x1,y1 x2,y2`, поэтому в коде и добавлена заглушка.

Подскажите, как можно это исправить? Я думаю, что нужно как-то "достроить" прямоугольник до точки `x3, y3`, а потом вычесть из общего числа точек количество точек на достроенной площади, но я не знаю, как это правильно реализовать в коде.

Comment: Что-то я не понял этот сложный алгоритм. Не проще ли пройтись по всем точкам прямоугольника и проверить расстояние до центра окружности?

Comment: А что имеется в виду под расстоянием? Декартово или манхэттенское?

Comment: @MBo судя по картинке декартово

Comment: @AlexeyTen, проще конечно, но хотелось этот алгоритм как-то допилить

Comment: "декартово" == "евклидово" ?

Comment: Надо найти площадь пересечения круга и прямоугольника.

Comment: Число целых точек внутри круга ищется заметанием  прямой за время пропорциональное радиусу. Заметание можно модифицировать чтобы учесть прямоугольник. Вопрос, можно ли быстрее?

Comment: @DanSazonov, расстояние вы считаете не правильно.

Comment: Дайте ссылку на проверяющую систему.

Comment: Видимо, заметание - лучшее что можно придумать.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Конечно, евклидово. "Это я с прямым углом перепутал"©

Comment: Помимо заметания можно построить пересечение круга и прямоугольника. Пересечение - не более чем восьмиугольник (некоторые стороны - дуги окружности). Дуги перевести в ломанные - будет честный многоугольник. К нему применить формулу Пика.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, доступ к проверяющей системе уже закрыт. Но спасибо за советы, узнал новую инфу

Answer (score 1):

*прошу прощения, что мой пост без кода. У меня правая рука в гипсе, очень неудобно набирать код. Слова же я диктую винде, их она распознает вполне прилично.*

это задача на заметание контура. Представьте, что слева из бесконечности накатывает прямая вертикальная линия. Как только она пересекает фигуру, подсчитываются крайняя верхняя и крайняя нижняя точки. Оптимизация разумеется заключается в том, чтобы накатывать не из бесконечности до бесконечности а только в пределах ограничивающего прямоугольника (bounding rectangle).

В вашем случае я бы поступил так:

1. Сместил бы начало координат центр окружности.
2. Нашел бы пересечение ограничивающего прямоугольника круга и заданного прямоугольника.  Очевидно что все точки , который вам нужно найти, лежат именно в этом прямоугольнике. Дальше в описании алгоритма, когда я буду говорить прямоугольник, я буду подразумевать именно этот прямоугольник.
3. Если построенный прямоугольник пуст — прекрасно. Пересечение круга и исходного прямоугольника пусто. Ноль точек. Завершение работы .

Так как у вас пересечение фигур устроено очень регулярно, то простой алгоритм поиска контура можно немного оптимизировать.

4. Для начала я бы ещё немножко преобразовал координаты . Переместим тот угол построенного прямоугольника, в котором сумма квадратов координат максимальна, в левый верхний угол. Этого можно добиться не более чем 2 отражениями вокруг осей координат.
5. Если квадрат расстояния до левого верхнего угла меньше квадрата радиуса окружности, очень хорошо. Это означает, что весь прямоугольник лежит внутри окружности. Тогда искомое число точек -- это число точек внутри прямоугольника. Завершение работы .
6. Если квадрат расстояния до каждой из вершин построенного прямоугольника больше квадрата радиуса круга, и все вершины построенного прямоугольника лежат в одном квадранте - это тоже хорошо. Построенный прямоугольник лежит вне круга, и число точек равно нулю.
7. Теперь нужно найти самую левую вертикаль которая пересекается одновременно и с кругом и с построенным прямоугольником.

7.1 Если левые вершины прямоугольника лежат по разные стороны оси икс, то левая вертикаль гарантированно пересекается с кругом. Найти точки пересечения можно лобовым перебором всех точек левой стороны, либо делением отрезка пополам либо из тригонометрических соображений.

7.2. Если обе левых вершины находятся в одном квадранте то нужно понять, пересекается ли эта сторона с кругом.

7.2.1. Если квадрат расстояния до левой нижней вершины меньше квадрата радиуса, то пересечение есть. Найти точку пересечения можно лобовым перебором всех точек левой стороны, либо делением отрезка пополам либо из тригонометрических соображений.

7.2.2. В противном случае нужно двигаться вдоль нижней стороны прямоугольника до пересечения с кругом. Найти точку пересечения можно лобовым перебором всех точек нижней стороны слева направо, либо делением отрезка пополам либо из тригонометрических соображений. Пересечение должно быть, так как на 6 шаге мы установили что общие точки у прямоугольника и круга должны быть. От найденной точки нужно пойти вверх, чтобы найти все точки интервала пересечения.

8. На 7 шаге была найдена вертикаль, у которой есть общие точки с кругом и прямоугольником. Число точек из интервала пересечения нужно сохранить в ответ. И запомнить верхние и нижние точки этого интервала.
9. Сдвигаем вертикаль на один шаг вправо.

9.1. Если прямоугольник закончился завершаем работу

9.2. Ищем границы интервала на новый вертикали. Очевидно, что для этого не нужно сканировать всю вертикаль так как точки пересечения на следующей вертикали должны быть рядом с граничными точками интервала на предыдущей вертикали.

10. Если интервал на новый вертикали пуст , заканчиваем работу. Мы вышли за границу круга.
11. В противном случае добавляем число точек найденного интервала к ответу и переходим снова на шаг 9.